# How to write a trigger that refreshes LWC data-table?

Tags: lightning-datatable

I have a trigger that stores data, the data is then displayed on a lightning data-table when the web page is first loaded. I have @wired the logList function but data-table doesn't refresh and update when new data is stored. Is there a way to use refreshApex in a Trigger to get real-time updates?

js:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getLog from '@salesforce/apex/FridgeLogsController.getLog';

const columns = [
    {label: 'Timestamp', fieldName: 'LastModifiedDate', type: 'date',
        typeAttributes:{
            weekday: "long",
            year: "numeric",
            month: "long",
            day: "2-digit",
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit"
        }
    },
    {label: 'Employee Name', fieldName: 'employeeName__c', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Fridge ID', fieldName: 'fridgeId__c', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Phone #', fieldName: 'contactPhone', type: 'phone'},
];

export default class ExerciseTrigger extends LightningElement {
    columns = columns;
    refreshTable;
    @track log;

    @wire(getLog) logList(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.refreshTable = result;
            this.error = undefined;

            let preparedArr = [];
            result.data.forEach(record => {
                let preparedRec = {};
                preparedRec.Id = record.Id;
                preparedRec.date = record.LastModifiedDate;
                preparedRec.LastModifiedDate = record.LastModifiedDate;
                preparedRec.employeeName__c = record.employeeName__c;
                preparedRec.fridgeId__c = record.fridgeId__c;
                preparedRec.contactPhone = record.Contact__r.Phone;

                preparedArr.push(preparedRec);
            });
            this.log = [...preparedArr];
            
        } else if (result.data) {
            this.log = result.error;
            this.error = undefined;
        } 
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger FridgeTrigger on Fridge_Log__e (after insert) {
    // List to insert
    list<Fridge_Logs__c> dataToInsert = new List<Fridge_Logs__c>();
    
    for (Fridge_Log__e event : Trigger.New) {
        System.debug('Data ID from emitter: ' + event.badgeId__c);
        // Record to add
        Fridge_Logs__c data = new Fridge_Logs__c();
        // Store event into variable for storing
        data.badgeId__c = event.badgeId__c;
        data.employeeName__c = event.employeeName__c;
        data.fridgeId__c = event.fridgeId__c;
        List<Contact> lookupList = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = :data.employeeName__c ];
        data.Contact__c = lookupList[0].Id;
        dataToInsert.add(data);
        
        if(!dataToInsert.isEmpty()){
            // Record data in db
            insert dataToInsert;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not, you can't call refreshApex from Apex. Instead, you can use lightning-emp-api to listen for Platform Events, which you can use EventBus.publish to fire notifications from your trigger.